# Error in testing application on android device after connecting to android studio via wifi

Tags: java, android, json, adb

I did follow this [Connect to wifi tutorial](http://stuffandtech.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-quick-tip-adb-over-wifi.html) and i was able to connect my phone to my desktop through wifi(router) and i am able to test almost all application wirelessly except those require JSON parsing. I am using wamp server and it is running but i am getting forbidden error.

This is the error in logcat. Can anyone tell me how shall i get rid of this error??
Also in my source code of the application, i did add the ip address of my desktop like this 192.168.0.105/test/stock.php instead of 10.10.0.2

My application works perfectly on the emulator but i am not able to run it on the device.

> 04-25 20:07:11.172  11847-11874/com.e.myapplication I/System.out﹕
>   ERROR : Forbidden 04-25 20:07:11.172  11847-11874/com.e.myapplication
>   I/System.out﹕ error 04-25 20:07:11.172 
>   11847-11847/com.e.myapplication E/log_tag﹕ Error parsing data
>   org.json.JSONException: Value error of type java.lang.String cannot be
>   converted to JSONArray

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29)? It clearly states that JSONException "If there is a syntax error in the source string or a duplicated key".

Comment: but my application works perfectly on the emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem changing a setting in the Apache httpd.conf.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

I changed it to

```
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

And now my mobile can access the web service.

Answer (score 1):

> > Value error of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

means that you probably try to map something like this :

```
name="value"
```

to an array.

So your Json is wrongly formatted, you must have something like this :

```
name=["value"]
```

---

Since your app works correctly in the emulator, it's probably a communication error. The error you see is certainly the consequence of something else. Look at previous logs and log the json string you are trying to parse. (I'm pretty sure it is not at all what you expect)

Comment: I managed to solve the problem changing a setting in the Apache httpd.conf.

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
I changed it to

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
And now my mobile can access the web service. I am unaware if there is a better way to do this.